Device Manager - Windows changes power settings without my permission
I have a touchpad problem with my settings in Device Manager in Windows 11.
I have drivers that control the touchpad on my laptop (Dell Precision 7780). I have set the "Allow the computer to turn off the device to save power" setting unchecked on all of my touchpad/I2C/HID drivers.
Windows will randomly enable this setting without my permission after the computer goes to sleep. The result is that sometimes when I wake my laptop from Sleep, the touchpad is not working. The only way to get the touchpad working again is to completely shutdown the computer (restart does not work).
How do I stop Windows from changing this setting? The change is happening automatically and I want it to stop.
Other relevant info:

This is a brand new computer
This happens with the factory drivers and the updated most recent drivers directly from Microsoft and Intel
The touchpad has already been replaced with a new touchpad by a Dell tech and Dell tech support has no other ideas, behavior still occurs
My user account is an Administrator account, Windows still changes the setting without notification or permission
I already have all of the newest Dell software updates and Windows updates, including BIOS updates

